# URL Not Returning Data Delphi Indy TIdHttp

Tags: delphi, indy, idhttp

I am trying to access a URL in Delphi using a TIdHTTP Indy Tool.
I have done the following:

- Set Accept Cookies = True
- Set Handle Redirect = True
- Added a TIdCookieManager

`http://sms.saicomvoice.co.za:8900/saicom/index.php?action=login&username=SOME_USERNAME&password=SOME_PASSWORD&login=login`

The Post request works and it returns the HTML. The problem is it doesn't return the correct HTML (See Image Below).

If I take that URL ( Filling in the username and password ) and paste it into my browser exactly The Same as my Delphi Application would then logs into the correct website. But as soon as I do it with my Delphi App it returns the HTML for the login page.

The request is supposed to be executed timeously in a TTimer in Delphi.

Can anyone lead me unto the right path or point me in a direction as to how I can solve this problem ?

***Some Additional Information***

- WriteStatus is a Procedure That writes output to a TListBox
- BtnEndPoll Stops the timer

  ```
  Procedure TfrmMain.TmrPollTimer(Sender: TObject);
  Var
    ResultHTML: String;
    DataToSend: TStringList;
  Begin
    Inc(Cycle, 1);

    LstStatus.Items.Add('');
    LstStatus.Items.Add('==================');
    WriteStatus('Cycle : ' + IntToStr(Cycle));
    LstStatus.Items.Add('==================');
    LstStatus.Items.Add('');

    DataToSend := TStringList.Create;

    Try
      WriteStatus('Setting Request Content Type');
      HttpRequest.Request.ContentType := 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8';
      WriteStatus('Setting Request User Agent');
      HttpRequest.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:2.0b8) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0b8';

      WriteStatus('Posting Request');
      ResultHTML := HttpRequest.Post(FPostToURL, DataToSend);
      WriteStatus('Writing Result');
      FLastResponse := ResultHTML;

      WriteStatus('Cycle : ' + IntToStr(Cycle) + ' -- FINISHED');
      LstStatus.Items.Add('');
    Except
      On E: Exception Do
        Begin
          MakeNextEntryError := True;
          WriteStatus('An Error Occured: ' + E.Message);

          If ChkExceptionStop.Checked Then
            Begin
              BtnEndPoll.Click;
              WriteStatus('Stopping Poll Un Expectedly!');
            End;
        End;
    End;
  End;
  ```

*** Image Example ***

[image: HTML Output]

Comment: could you include the relevant part of the HTML as text instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> HttpRequest.Request.ContentType := 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8';

That is not a valid `ContentType` value.  That kind of value belongs in the `Request.Accept` property instead.  It tells the server which ContentTypes the client will accept in the response.

> ResultHTML := HttpRequest.Post(FPostToURL, DataToSend);

You are posting a blank `TStringList`. Putting a URL into a browser's address bar sends a `GET` request, not a `POST` request, so you should be using `TIdHTTP.Get()` instead:

```
ResultHTML := HttpRequest.Get('http://sms.saicomvoice.co.za:8900/saicom/index.php?action=login&username=SOME_USERNAME&password=SOME_PASSWORD&login=login');
```

You would use `TIdHTTP.Post()` if you wanted to simulate the HTML webform being submitted to the server (since it specifies `method=post`), eg:

```
DataToSend.Add('username=SOME_USERNAME');
DataToSend.Add('password=SOME_PASSWORD');
DataToSend.Add('login=Login');
ResultHTML := HttpRequest.Post('http://sms.saicomvoice.co.za:8900/saicom/index.php?action=login', DataToSend);
```

Comment: I've added the Get Request, but for some reason it is as if it is not posting the actual data, because it still returns the login page HTML

Comment: Never Mind. I found the problem and fixed it. Thank you your solution helped